# How to display local Word file on page?

Tags: html, iframe

I have tried this iFrame to display Word files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .doc {
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe class="doc" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://writing.engr.psu.edu/workbooks/formal_report_template.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

This works fine for files **online**.
How do I do the same with files in my **localhost**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

You need to host it somewhere for Google Docs to load it from.

Comment: It's going online later, but for for now I'm testing thing locally.
File links are in the database. Is it possible to view a Word file from the database? (when it's already online)

Comment: @sventastic: You just need to serve it from a URL for Google Docs to load.